# Error: "Cannot assign a value of type String: UIColor? to a value of type String: AnyObject!"

Tags: ios, swift2, uicolor

My code worked fine in Swift 1.2 but in Swift 2 I am getting this error:

> Cannot assign a value of type String: UIColor? to a value of type String: AnyObject!

My Code is:

```
 override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = super.collectionView(collectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath: indexPath) as! JSQMessagesCollectionViewCell

    let message = messages[indexPath.row]

    if message.senderId == self.senderId {
        cell.textView!.textColor = UIColor.blackColor()
    } else {
        cell.textView!.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    }

    // Error in the following line 
    cell.textView!.linkTextAttributes = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName:cell.textView!.textColor]

    return cell
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to add a `!` after the `textColor`:

```
cell.textView!.linkTextAttributes = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName:cell.textView!.textColor!]
```

Reason for that being that `linkTextAttributes` is of type `[String : AnyObject!]` while the dictionary you want to assign is of type `[String : UIColor?]`. The mismatch between `UIColor` and `AnyObject` because `UIColor` can be cast to `AnyObject`. The problem is the that the `UIColor?` you provide is optional. And you cannot implicitly cast the optional `UIColor?` to a non-optional `AnyObject!`. Therefore **you** have to force-unwrap the color to get a `UIColor` from the `UIColor?` by adding a `!`.

Comment: Thanks man! It's working :). I'm sorry I cannot up vote your answer because I'm new here and I don't have enough reputation(at least 15 needed).

Comment: You can up vote my question so that I will get 10 reputation(I think) and I already have 5

Answer (score 0):

Try with this

```
textView!.linkTextAttributes = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName:textView!.textColor as AnyObject!]
```